# How SurfaceFlinger instance get used by the application in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to understand SurfaceFlinger code of Android framework. I have not been able to  understand when the `readytorun` method of SurfaceFlinger get called? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceFlinger inherits also the Thread class (among other classes), so readyToRun() is the method where various  initialization pieces should be placed since it gets called in the first steps of the newly created thread ([_threadLoop()](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/utils/Threads.cpp#779); for JB check frameworks/native/libs/utils/Threads.cpp).

SurfaceFlinger thread is started in the surfaceflinger process (main_surfaceflinger.cpp) as one of the first Android processes (shortly after the booting - right before the boot animation is shown on the screen). Inside [main_surfaceflinger.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/cmds/surfaceflinger/main_surfaceflinger.cpp), the Surfaceflinger service is registered to the ServiceManager and the SurfaceFlinger thread is started (among other various things).